# Decompose a Mobius transformation to understand what it does.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, mobius-transformation

I understood that a Mobius transformation can be decomposed into a composition of elementary operations, e.g., rotation, dilation, and inversion.

Here, I'm facing the following transformation to understand;
$f(z) = \frac{z + 2}{3z + 4}$.
I could factorise it till the following but was not sure how to understand the remaining factor.
$f(z) = f_1 \circ f_2 \circ f_3 \circ f_4$

$$
f_4: z \mapsto 3z, f_3: z \mapsto z + 4, f_2: z \mapsto 1/z, f_1: z \mapsto z * z;
$$.

Then I got the remaining term of $\frac{+2}{3z + 4}$. How can I deal with this?

Comment: I suggest finding the fixed points $\,f(z)=z.\,$ If there are two, then it is a dilation conjugated to fixed points $0$ and $\,\infty\,$. If there is only one, then it is a translation conjugating the fixed point to $\,\infty.$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_transformation#Simple_Möbius_transformations_and_composition

Comment: Would it help if you wrote $\frac{3z+4}{z+2}$ as $3-\frac{2}{z+2}$?

Comment: …or maybe write $\frac{z+2}{3z+4}=\frac13+\frac{\frac23}{3z+4}$?

Comment: @DavidQuinn, Thank you so much for your detailed and almost-answer advice! That helped me to decompose the function and intuitively understand how it works step by step!

Comment: You are welcome